# Not able to access a bundle at a given path in ios

Tags: ios, frameworks, bundle, xcode9.2

Not able to access a bundle at a given path in ios. The code is as follows :

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"];
if (![bundle load]) {
   NSLog(@"Error"); // maybe throw an exception
} else {
   _supporter = [NSClassFromString(@"BCBatteryDevice") valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"];
   _handler = [[BCBatteryDeviceHandler alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it returns nil in "bundle"

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `bundleWithPath`? Could you consider `Bundle(anyClass: SomeClassFromTheBundle.self)`?

Comment: Or is that initialiser not existent on `NSBundle`? I use it in Swift `Bundle`.

Comment: I actually am trying to access a private framework, for some research purpose, and therefore want to access the private framework to load the bundle